# How to hide a window's menubar?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, menu

I'm trying to hide the menubar in a C++ application using the windows API. I'm using [AppendMenu / RemoveMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to edit items. But I'm sick of the whole menu based interface and I just want to hide the whole application menubar. How can I do that using the windows API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call [SetMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647995%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a NULL `HWND` parameter, according to the docs.

Comment: Er, that code does that. In order for it to show again, you'd have to call `SetMenu` passing the menu handle. If you don't want a menu, why are you even creating one?